# Best way to merge key value pairs in a hash based on number of values for that key in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, key

I have a hash of arrays in ruby as :

```
 @people = { "a" => ["john", "mark", "tony"], "b"=> ["tom","tim"], 
            "c" =>["jane"], "others"=>["rob", "ryan"] }
```

I would like to merge all key value pairs where there are less than 3 items in the array for a particular keys values. They should be merged into the key called "others" to give roughly the result of

```
 @people = { "a" => ["john", "mark", "tony"], 
           "others"=> ["rob", "ryan", "tom", "tim", "jane"] }
```

Using the following code is problematic as duplicate key values in a hash cannot exist:

```
 @people = Hash[@people.map{|k,v| v.count<3 ? ["others",v] : [k,v]} ] %>
```

Whats the best way to elegantly solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it, the problem is, as you notice, that you can't build the Hash's key/value pairs on the fly because of duplicates. One way around the problem is to start out with the skeleton of what you're trying to build:

```
@people = @people.each_with_object({ 'others' => [ ] }) do |(k,v), h|
    if(v.length >= 3)
        h[k] = v
    else
        h['others'] += v
    end
end
```

Or, if you don't like `each_with_object`, you could:

```
h = { 'others' => [ ] }
@people.each do |k, v|
    # as above
end
@people = h
```

Or you could use pretty much the same structure with `inject` (taking care, as usual, to return the right thing from the block).

There are certainly other ways to do this but these approaches are pretty clear and easy to understand; IMO clarity should be your first goal.

Comment: thanks first solution using each_with_object worked well and solved it ! great thanks

Comment: interestingly this worked in development but not when put into production - any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that you have `length > 3` arrays in production?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. The only logic is a simple `v.length >= 3` test and I don't see how that could possibly fail. Have you added a few `Rails.logger.info` calls so that you can watch what's going on?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26793/discussion-between-ryan-perera-and-mu-is-too-short)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
>> @people = { "a" => ["john", "mark", "tony"], "b"=> ["tom","tim"], 
        "c" =>["jane"], "others"=>["rob", "ryan"] }

>> @new_people = {"others" => []}

>> @people.each_pair {|k,v| (v.size >= 3 && k!="others") ? @new_people.merge!(k=>v) : @new_people['others']+= v}    

>> @new_people
=> {"others"=>["rob", "ryan", "jane", "tom", "tim"], "a"=>["john", "mark", "tony"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[ @people.group_by { |k,v| v.size < 3 ? 'others' : k }.
              map { |k,v| [k, v.flat_map(&:last)] } ]

=> {"a"=>["john", "mark", "tony"],
    "others"=>["tom", "tim", "jane", "rob", "ryan"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
> less_than_three, others = @people.partition {|(key, values)| values.size >= 3 }
> Hash[less_than_three]
# => {"a"=>["john", "mark", "tony"]}
> Hash["others" => others.map {|o| o.last}.flatten]
# => {"others"=>["tom", "tim", "jane", "rob", "ryan"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@people[:others] = []
@people.each do |k, v|
  @people[:others] |= @people.delete(k) if v.size < 3
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@people.inject({}) do |m, (k, v)|
  m[i = v.size >= 3 ? k : 'others'] = m[i].to_a + v
  m
end
```

Comment: you can remove a line using `each_with_object`